# UITableView to PDF with many pages(cannot generate)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pdf, ios8

I'm trying to generate PDF from the whole content of tableView. I've tried (I think) all examples from stackoverflow and they work only in the case where tableView's rows fits within single pdf page. Any data that contains more than 1 page can't be generated.

Currently using this snippet:(sorry, don't remember the author)

```
        var pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0, 0, 612,792), nil);
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        self.view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), animated:false)
        self.tableView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

        let screensInTable:CGFloat = self.tableView.contentSize.height / self.tableView.frame.height;
        print("how many screens: \(screensInTable)")
        for i in 1..<Int(screensInTable) {
            let contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGFloat(i) * 100)//self.tableView.frame.height
            print("content offset: \(contentOffset)")
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated:false)
            self.tableView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        }

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

        let activityViewController =  UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData], applicationActivities: nil)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
```

The problem is at line: self.tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated:false)
commenting it, all pages are generated but only the first has content. when leaving like this, in activityViewController-> print preview is endlessly loading the preview

I've also tried to render single contentView of cell but when iterating through tableView.subviews it only contains views of visible cells

Answer (score 0):

I have generated PDF for tableView even when the content weren't visible.

The main logic is using

`CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);`

If the `y` values are translated to negative, then the content shifts itself upwards so that you can snapshot the next set. If not you'll just receive the viewable screenshot only.

The following is the code snippet that I used for generating image from tableView

```
func getScreenShot(aView : UIView, forRect rect : CGRect) -> UIImage {
    // Preserve the previous frame and contentOffset of the scrollView (tableView)
    let frame = aView.frame
    var offset : CGPoint?

    // Get offset only if view is scrollView
    if let aView = aView as? UIScrollView {
        offset = aView.contentOffset
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

    // Move the frame for the screenshot starting position
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);

    // Set the new size for the view
    aView.frame.size = rect.size

    // Set the new contentOffset for the view only if it's a scrollView
    if let aView = aView as? UIScrollView {
        aView.contentOffset.y = rect.origin.y
    }

    aView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(rect, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Reset the previous frame
    aView.frame = frame

    // Reset offset only if view is scrollView
    if let aView = aView as? UIScrollView {
        aView.contentOffset = offset!
    }

    return image
}
```

You can modify this to your need. Also I would suggest you to use

`drawViewHierarchyInRect(rect, afterScreenUpdates: true)`

if you're supporting iOS 7 and above because it's much faster than `renderInContext`.

Comment: still doesn't work unfortunately :( ended up creating html and sending it as a report